# How do I use dotEnv when there is no .env file?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables

I have a project that locally has a `.env` file.  When I set up the environment variables on my local machine I use:

```
import dotEnv from "dotenv";
dotEnv.config();
```

It find the `.env` and loads up all the variables.  When I push the project to Heroku, I don't push up the `.env` file.  I expected `dotEnv` to understand that, but I get this error:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'
```

How do I get around that I am not pushing up a `.env` file?  What is the proper way to use `.dotEnv`?

Comment: Why do you expect dotenv to work without the .env file? If you want your config variables to be loaded push your  .env file as well.

Comment: the `dotenv` project strongly suggests that you don't push your `.env` file.   I found the answer in this thread.  https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/126

Answer (score 2):

I'm a contributor to the dotenv module. You can safely ignore this error. It is returned for your convenience in case something isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't much like the solution proposed here: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/126  It amounts to conditionally requiring /dotenv depending on an environment variable being set.  This seems brittle and like extra work to me.

The neatest solution for this I've found doesn't pollute my production code with any references to dotenv at all.  Just include dotenv in your dev dependencies and run your app locally using the node require switch:

```
$ node -r dotenv/config ./lib/index.js
```

This is the same way you might load babel-register.

Now your code doesn't care about where the env variables come from. Works with nodemon, etc. too. You can even specify an alternate env file:

```
$ node -r dotenv/config your_script.js dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/your/env/vars
```

It's all on the npm page for the package.